# javascript function is working but the same in jQuery ajax function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am a newbie here as I have never asked any question. Only by searching, I have got many questions answered. For the first time, trying to get help like this. Please let me know if my question is vague by any chance.

Question is: In my application, html page sends a request for downloading a file and server responds with application/octet-stream for the same to give that zip file as download. This is perfectly working when I tried with a javascript function like this --

```
function downloadFun() 
{
alert("in downloadFun");
document.searchForm.action = "http://localhost:8080/DatasetRepo/rest/downloadAny?";
document.forms["searchForm"].submit();
}
```

But when I do the same thing, with jQuery ajax method like below --

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("button").click(function(){  
     $.ajax({
     url: "http://localhost:8080/DatasetRepo/rest/downloadAny",
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "application/octet-stream"  
     });   
   });   
 });
```

is not working. Tried looking in firebug, its showing the response in some format like this -

```
�b�d�A#.Iio�8�N��ȿ���#Q7.os��9_o�߳4(@�d�� ��B."����w�ݪ�,����.[�
```

Could you please help me in this?

Comment: Why do you need ajax to do this?

Comment: that is to make post request with some json parameters.

Comment: How does your form look like?

Comment: my form will have POST method type. (Here I have tried with GET just to check how it works) In my form, some dynamic table got from another request. results can be selected and click on download button should give a download zip file of that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Becase is not the same function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
  $("#searchForm").attr("action","http://localhost:8080/DatasetRepo/rest/downloadAny?");
  $("#searchForm").submit();
 });
});
```

Sorry "searchForm" is the id attribute of the form, not the name, so I fixed the code

Comment: What do you mean by "not the same function"

Comment: Submitting a form and ajaxing a form is not the same technology. Not to mention you want to post but you use GET

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried with GET for making it POST afterwards if it works. Now, this is perfectly working with the given suggestion. Could you please suggest how to send some parameters in json format by making it POST request in this way...

Comment: It means that an ajax request is not the same of a form submit

Comment: But even with     form[name=searchForm]     also worked perfectly as I have this as name attribute of my form.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your patience and help. Yah, understood the concept now. But how to send my json request parameters and get that download accordingly...?